# Streaming binary data to server using Net::HTTP in ruby

Tags: ruby, uri

Using Ruby, I just try to parse the bitstream file to the server, I have a problem with badrequst HTTP. Could anybody help me with sending the data to the server by using Net::HTTP.

```
  def addbitstream(url, path, file_bitstream)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(path)

  f = File.new(file_bitstream)
  file = File.open(f)
  n = 6
  offset = 0
  request.body = ""

  while (offset < File.size(file))
    buffer = readfileAsbitstream(file, offset, n)
    request.body = buffer
    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, 443) {|http| http.request(request) }

    offset += n
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not done file streaming, the first problem you will have with this code is that `HTTP.start` closes the connection after executing a block, when it is passed one. Maybe changing the order of your nesting here will help.

I would recommend using a gem to wrap HTTP requests anyway such as [REST-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client), which I think streams file uploads by default.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, do you have any idea over the sending data to server?I wanna send every chunks to server by NET::HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use  `Net::HTTP`:

```
url ="www.yoururl.com"
uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
http.use_ssl = true 
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
response = http.request(request)
```